# Trying to login to a website using HttpWebRequest & HttpWebResponse throws an error

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

So I am currently learning HttpWebRequests & Responses because I love the idea of automating my online work for me.
So after reading a bit about it I decided to start by something simple, maybe login to a website because that's something I do quite frequently.
I decided to try it with Spotify because the website is just so plain and simple and I thought that it would be a great place to start at.

So what I have so far is this but I keep getting an error

> System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (405)
>   Method Not Allowed.'

Are there a specific set of steps I should follow when trying to login? What am I looking for? I used fiddler to grab ahold of the postData parameters (Not sure if those are the right ones, I think I need more)
If I am missing any steps feel free to fill me in on what I am doing wrong here.

```
protected static CookieContainer Login()
        {
            string userName = "myUsername";
            string password = "myPassword";

            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData = "username=" + userName + "&password=" + password;
            byte[] postDataBytes = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.spotify.com/en-EN/login");

            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postDataBytes.Length;
            httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(postDataBytes, 0, postDataBytes.Length);
                stream.Close();
            }

            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
//This is where it throws the error
            using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    foreach (Cookie cookie in httpWebResponse.Cookies)
                    {
                        cookieContainer.Add(cookie);
                    }
                }
            }

            return cookieContainer;
        }
```

Comment: `https://accounts.spotify.com/en-EN/login` is the address of the page that presents the login form, not the address that the form is submitted to.  Using Chrome Dev tools you can see it actually posts to  `https://accounts.spotify.com/api/login`.  Also you'll need to make sure you url encode your username and password, and you may have to also submit a csrf_token, which you'd have to extract from the HTML returned by a GET on the original address. You might want to consider using HttpClient BTW, it has functionality to make posting forms easier.

Comment: Wow! Youre a wizard! So the token, is that one that generates newly everytime or can I reuse mine? What steps did you take to find all this information? I am so impressed!!

Comment: Like I said, all I did is use the Network monitor in Chrome Dev tools. Most browsers have the same functionality.

Comment: Just install [fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and perform the actions you want to capture. From there you can build and compare results.

Comment: BTW I did a bit more hunting into it - the csrf_token is not trivial to get.  You may even have to use some sort of embedded web browser to get it, as it appears to require executing javascript.